# How do you prevent the On-Screen Keyboard from showing up when selecting text fields in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. This is **NOT** the bug that causes the keyboard to pop up whenever the touchscreen is touched. Thank God I don't have that.

Whenever I touch a text field on the touchscreen, the on-screen keyboard pops up. This is annoying because I have an actual physical keyboard attached to my laptop that I prefer to use instead. I don't have any touchscreen-related tweaks installed. Block Caribou had no effect. [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenismus-team/+archive/ubuntu/openismus-meego-im) is broken and doesn't install. The On-Screen Keyboard is disabled in Universal Access.

I wouldn't mind if the on-screen keyboard was completely removed. I don't use it at all. I'm using a Huawei Matebook D, in case that matters.

Comment: IIRC that's `onboard` and can be removed with `sudo apt purge onboard` - which will also clear out any config files for it.

Comment: @KGIII `onboad` isn't installed